# Moving content between databases in MarkLogic using nifi

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi

I am currently testing Apache nifi by attempting to move content from one MarkLogic database to another within the same cluster. I am having troubles deleting the content from the original database.

I have flowfiles describing the batches of content that moved into my subdatabase, how can I use that to delete from the original database?

I have looked at [`DeleteMarkLogic`](https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/nifi-features#deletemarklogic-processor) and [`ExtensionCallMarkLogic`](https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/nifi-features#extensioncallmarklogic-processor) processors, but I have been unable to get either to work in this case. `DeleteMarkLogic` requires a query, and even though I set `ExtensionCallMarkLogic` to use the [DELETE /v1/Documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/DELETE/v1/documents) endpoint, it sent a **GET** request instead.

How can I remove the moved content in a timely fashion so that I do not present duplicate data back to search?

Comment: Did you set the "Method" property on ExtensionCallMarkLogic to "DELETE"? Also, while DeleteMarkLogic does require a query, what prevents you from constructing a query to describe the documents to delete? And approximately how many documents are you moving?

Comment: Yes, the method is set to DELETE.  We are testing against a collection of 3.2 million documents, with the eventual goal of moving 900 million total documents to other subdatabases.  We have also noticed that the QueryMarkLogic processor is apparently able to make requests against the entire cluster, not just the initial host set by MarkLogicDatabaseClientService.

Comment: If those 3.2m documents are in a collection, it seems like you could use DeleteMarkLogic with a cts.collectionQuery? Also, both QueryMarkLogic and DeleteMarkLogic will use the host specified by the DatabaseClientService to find all of the hosts in the cluster and then spread load across all of them.

Comment: I need to delete the content as soon as it gets written to the sub database, or else I return duplicate content, which is not ideal.  That was why nifi seemed so appealing as it could manage a batch of records through a pipeline.

Comment: Right, that sounds good, so can you use DeleteMarkLogic with a cts.collectionQuery or some other query that describes the data to delete? If you only want to delete the URIs associated with e.g. a FlowFile, you could always construct a cts.documentQuery on the fly that deletes those specific URIs.

Comment: I would really prefer to pass in a flow file to DeleteMarkLogic, but I am working on other ways to construct the query.